# Tool to validate naming style in VB.NET following Hungarian notation

Tags: asp.net, static-analysis, vb.net-2010, hungarian-notation

I'm maintaining a legacy ASP.NET website written in VB.NET. Our customers force us to use Hungarian notation for declaring variables and such:

E.g:

```
Dim sSomeString as String
Dim oSomeObject as xxxClass
```

Is there any tool like FxCop, StyleCop, ReSharper that can help me determine the code that violate this naming style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm part of SubMain, the company that makes CodeIt.Right)

Yes, there is a tool that will do that. While the recommended shipped rule set is aiming at MS .NET Guidelines, [**CodeIt.Right**](http://submain.com/codeit.right) also ships with rules that help to enforce Hungarian notation as well as refactorings to automatically fix incorrect names. It even has rules that help you convert Hungarian notation into MS .NET recommended naming conventions.

Contact customer service via email link on our web site and they will point you to the appropriate set of rules to use.